# print all view controller content

Tags: ios, swift

I found this code that works, but I need to somehow change it so that it prints the entire scroll view. This code only prints whats displaying on the screen.

```
 @IBAction func btnPrint(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    let printArea = pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: tableView)

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [printArea], applicationActivities: nil)

    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
    let priorBounds = tableView.bounds
    let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:priorBounds.size.width, height:tableView.contentSize.height))
    tableView.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:fittedSize.width, height:fittedSize.height)
    let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height)
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds,nil)
    var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
    while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
        tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
        pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    tableView.bounds = priorBounds
    var docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
    docURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDocument.pdf")
    pdfData.write(to: docURL as URL, atomically: true)
}
```

}

Comment: What modifications did you try? What didn't work?

Comment: I tried altering this line of code:  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale). It's only printing whats in the screen review, but there is more information below that needs to be included in the print.

Comment: note may viewcontroller displays a UItableview